# Added SQL query criteria returns wrong data set

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a table of jobs, with fields that include date of last cost update, work billed, revised contract amount, and payments. I want to only return records where the amount billed, contracted and paid are equal in the row.

I have a query that works for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM JCM_MASTER__JOB
WHERE (((JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Work_Billed)=[Revised_Contract_Amount]) AND          
((JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Payments)=[JTD_Work_Billed]));
```

However, I also have additional criteria, such as the date of last cost entry
    ((JCM_MASTER__JOB.Last_Cost_Update)<=#12/31/2012#)

When I add the date criteria though, it is only returning records where JTD_Work_Billed, Revisited_Contract_Amount and JTD_Payments are ALL equal to 0.

The full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM JCM_MASTER__JOB
WHERE (((JCM_MASTER__JOB.Last_Cost_Update)<=#12/31/2012#) AND         
((JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Work_Billed)=[Revised_Contract_Amount]) AND  
((JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Payments)=[JTD_Work_Billed]));
```

Why is this only returning records where billing, contract and payments are 0?
I am running this in Microsoft Access with ODBC connection to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM JCM_MASTER__JOB
WHERE (
  (
   (JCM_MASTER__JOB.Last_Cost_Update<=#12/31/2012#)
  ) AND
  (
   (JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Work_Billed=[Revised_Contract_Amount]) AND  
   (JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Payments=[JTD_Work_Billed])
  )
);
```

I added an extra set of parenthesis around the first criteria.

Assuming your `WHERE` clause is replaced with A, B and C arguments, you always want A, whereas you only want B if C is true and C if B is true.  So:

```
WHERE (  (A) AND (B AND C) )
```

Comment: This returns an error of an extra parentheses. I adjusted it, but still am not successful.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't see the extra sets you had earlier.  I adjusted the answer, with it formatted for parenthesis matching.

Comment: @SableFoste I'm afraid I don't follow your reasoning for the extra brackets. `WHERE (A AND B AND C)` and `WHERE (A AND (B AND C))` are logically equivalent, aren't they?

Comment: @GordThompson, logically they are the same, but semantically, they mean different things.  The idea is to help sort out the matching parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM JCM_MASTER__JOB
WHERE (JCM_MASTER__JOB.Last_Cost_Update<=#12/31/2012# AND JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Work_Billed=[Revised_Contract_Amount]) AND (JCM_MASTER__JOB.JTD_Payments=[JTD_Work_Billed]);
```

A lot of those parenthesis reduced readability

If that doesn't work, are you looking for records after or before 12/31/2012.  I'm sure you already checked but sometimes we miss it <= is for dates prior and >= for dates after.